# How well do 1980s AI Nikkor Lenses work on a Canon 60D with an adaptor?

Tags: canon, nikon, canon-60d, adapter, old-lenses

My dad has some old Nikkor AI Lenses from the 80's that are in great shape and are great all around lenses. I used to use them his Nikkormat growing up but now I want to use them on a digital format.

I want to buy a Canon 60D because of its video capabilities but how well do Canon -> Nikon adaptors work? Are there even adaptors that work with lenses that old?

Any advice? I'm not dead set on the 60D but I want the SLR to have great video capabilities.

Answer (score 5):

There are lots of adapters for Nikon lenses on Canon cameras.

With all of them, you'll get infinity focus, due to the fact that Canon's [lens registration](http://www.markerink.org/WJM/HTML/mounts.htm) is shorter than Nikon's.

What you'll forgo is autofocus and auto-stopdown during exposure. You will have to meter by stopping down, setting the exposure, opening up to focus, and then stopping down just before taking to shot.

With some Nikon DSLRs, basically from the D7000 and up, you can mount these lenses and the body will meter. You can use A and M modes. On cheaper models, you can mount the lens, but you will not get metering. You will however get auto stopdown when taking the shot.

There are some caveats though with lens compatibility. I'd use [Roland Vink's Nikon serial number database](http://www.photosynthesis.co.nz/nikon/serialno.html) to identify the lens mount variant on your dad's lenses. Anything newer than "AI" will mount fine on the D7000.

To add to the confusion, the Nikon->Canon lens adapter will not have any compatibility issues with different lens mount variants.

Answer (score 4):

I would look at the Nikon D7000 which has excellent video capabilities, is in a similar price range, and would eliminate the need for the Nikon-to-Canon adapter.

Comment: Nikon-Canon adaptors have no glass so there shouldn't be any image degradation.

Comment: Are there any compatibility issues to be aware of with that camera body (or other modern Nikon dSLRs) and older lenses?

Comment: + 1 this is perfectly reasonable. But I don't see how a lens-body adapter could cause image degradation.

Comment: @mattdm the Nikon D7000 has an Ai-tab, so it will meter and set exposure in A and M mode with nearly all Nikon lenses since around 1975.

Comment: Whoops, not sure why I was thinking there was glass involved since it's just a mount adapter.  I've removed that sentence.

Comment: Would any sort of adapter not cause a small amount of lost light?